# How to put every five rows into one sheet with xlwt and xlrd?

Tags: python, excel, xlrd, xlwt

**Now I can only save all 13 lines data to Sheet1. But in fact,I want to put every 5 rows in a sheet,for example:** 
[image]

**Now my code is like this:**

```
import xlwt
import xlrd
from xlutils.copy import copy
myyear = '2018'
myweek = '10'
mycd='1001'
fileName = myyear + myweek + '.xls'
workbook = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='UTF-8')
worksheet = workbook.add_sheet('sheet1')
worksheet.write(0, 0, label='year')
worksheet.write(0, 1, label='week')
worksheet.write(0, 2, label='CD')
worksheet.write(0, 3, label='keyword')
worksheet.write(0, 4, label='importance')
savePath = r'D:/' + fileName
workbook.save(savePath)
rexcel = xlrd.open_workbook(savePath)
rows = rexcel.sheets()[0].nrows
excel = copy(rexcel)
worksheet = excel.get_sheet(0)
current_row = rows
for cmp_noun, value in [[1,1],[2,2],[3,3],[4,4],[5,5],[6,6],[7,7],[8,8],[9,9],[10,10],[11,11],[12,12],[13,13]]:
    if current_row<=6:
        worksheet.write(current_row, 0, label=myyear)
        worksheet.write(current_row, 1, label=myweek)
        worksheet.write(current_row, 2, label=mycd)
        worksheet.write(current_row, 3, label=cmp_noun)
        worksheet.write(current_row, 4, label=value)
        current_row += 1
excel.save(savePath)
```

**How to modify the code to become the effect I want?**

Comment: check the grouper recipe from [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Structure your code in logical segments, so you can test each of those individually

## dummy data

Your dummy data can come from everywhere, here I made it a simple generator

```
def generate_data():
    year = '2018'
    week = '10'
    cd='1001'
    for i in range(1, 14):
        cmp_noun = value = i
        yield (year, week, cd, cmp_noun, value)
```

## grouping

```
from itertools import zip_longest
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    """
    Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks
    https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes
    """
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)

list(grouper(generate_data(), 5))
```

groups the data:

> ```
> [(('2018', '10', '1001', 1, 1),
>   ('2018', '10', '1001', 2, 2),
>   ('2018', '10', '1001', 3, 3),
>   ('2018', '10', '1001', 4, 4),
>   ('2018', '10', '1001', 5, 5)),
>  (('2018', '10', '1001', 6, 6),
>   ('2018', '10', '1001', 7, 7),
>   ('2018', '10', '1001', 8, 8),
>   ('2018', '10', '1001', 9, 9),
>   ('2018', '10', '1001', 10, 10)),
>  (('2018', '10', '1001', 11, 11),
>   ('2018', '10', '1001', 12, 12),
>   ('2018', '10', '1001', 13, 13),
>   None,
>   None)]
> ```

## Make the workbook

```
def generate_workbook(header, data, n=5):
    groups = grouper(data, n)
    workbook = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='UTF-8')
    for i, group in enumerate(groups, 1):
        worksheet = workbook.add_sheet(f'sheet{i}')
        group = filter(None, group)
        populate_sheet(worksheet=worksheet, header=header, data=group)
    return workbook
```

This groups the data, initiates a `WorkBook`. It then makes a new worksheet for each group, and populates it. The `filter(None, group)` is to discard the leftover rows when the data is not a multiple of `n`.

## populate the worksheet

```
def populate_sheet(worksheet, header, data):
    for i, column in enumerate(header):
        worksheet.write(0, i, column)
    for row_no, row in enumerate(data, 1):
        for i, item in enumerate(row):
            worksheet.write(row_no, i, label=item)
```

Writes the header to the first row, and then populates the following rows. Through the use of `enumerate` we eliminate a lot of the hard-coded numbers, and make this whole a lot more versatile

## saving the workbook

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    name = 'test.xls'
    data = generate_data()
    header = ['year', 'week', 'CD', 'keyword', 'importance']
    wb = generate_workbook(header=header, data=data, n = 5)
    wb.save(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get you started:

```
wb = Workbook()

for k in range(100):

    #create a new sheet 
    if not (k % 5):
        ws = wb.create_sheet('sheet {:d}'.format(k))

    # the rest is a bit of index magic using, indexing starts at 1 !
    ws.cell(row=1, column=1).value = 2
```